# How to display a link to the status of my latest tweet using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some help and would be VERY grateful for it. I would like to use Javascript to display a link to the status of my latest tweet. For example, it would be like:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/brianj_smith/status/57288271197241344">Read</a>
```

As you can see in the above code, the link is to my latest tweet. However, the latest tweet is (of course) going to change.... I can't seem to find anything online (I've been searching Google for a few hours) and I have been trying to create my own code with Twitter's API settings with no luck.

I hope that this is an easy question/problem to understand. If not I can provide more...

--- EDIT: Maybe it is because it's 3 AM where I am at, but I can't seem to get the jQuery to execute and show the link of the status and the text "Read" on my site. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the latest feed from Twitter using the JSONP API, specifying a count of 1. The service URL would look something like

```
"http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/brianj_smith.json?count=1&callback=callbackName"
```

jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) would be an easy choice here.

The URL of the latest status update would be (assuming data is returned as `data`)

```
"http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/" + data[0].id;
```

A working example is

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/brianj_smith.json?count=1&callback=?', function(data){
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var link = jQuery('<a>').attr('http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/' + data[0].id)
                                .text('Read');
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe it is because it's 3 AM where I am at, but I can't seem to get the jQuery to execute and show the link of the status and the text "Read" on my site. Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianJ I was getting "too many client requests" errors but it appears to be working now. Also, I think mine is the old API. You should use Jason's answer

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Twitter API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show) on this.

For instance, in jQuery:

```
$.get('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=noradio', {},
    function(response) { 
       $('#mydiv').text(response.status.text);
    }, 'json');
```

You may also find [this](http://dev.twitter.com/console?content_type=json&path=users/show) helpful

Comment: it's super easy if you're using jquery. `$(function(){ //above code });` you can also have it ping the api if you want to constantly refresh it in real time.